# Flux through surface (correct or not?)

Tags: integration, vector-fields, surface-integrals

I need to calculate the **flux** of the **vector field**

$$\mathbf{v}=(x-y,\; x+2y,\; z)$$

through the **surface**

$$S\, : \, \mathbf{r}(u, v)=(\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{2}},\, uv,\, \frac{v^2}{\sqrt{2}}),\;\; 0≤u≤1,\; -1≤v≤1,\; \mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{e}_x ≥0$$

I would like to know whether or not this is correct.

---

---

$$\mathbf{n}=\frac{(\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_u)}{|\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_u|},\;\;\; dS=|\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_u|dudv,\;\;\; d\mathbf{S}=(\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_u)dudv$$

$$(\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
\sqrt{2}u & v & 0 \\
0 & u & \sqrt{2}v \\
\end{bmatrix}=(\sqrt{2}v^2,\; -2uv ,\; \sqrt{2}u^2)$$

---

---

$$\iint\limits_S \mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{S}
=\iint\limits_S \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n}d\mathbf{S}
=\iint\limits_S \mathbf{v}\cdot (\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v)dudv
=$$
$$=\iint\limits_S(x-y,\; x+2y,\; z)\cdot (\sqrt{2}v^2,\; -2uv ,\; \sqrt{2}u^2)dudv=
$$
$$=\int\limits_{-1}^1
\left(\int\limits_0^1 \left(
(\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{2}}-uv,\; \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{2}}+2uv,\; \frac{v^2}{\sqrt{2}})\cdot (\sqrt{2}v^2,\; -2uv ,\; \sqrt{2}u^2)\right)du\right)dv=
$$
$$=\int\limits_{-1}^1
\left(\int\limits_0^1 \left((\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{2}}-uv)\sqrt{2}v^2+(\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{2}}+2uv)(-2uv)+\frac{v^2}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2}u^2\right)du\right)dv=$$
$$=\int\limits_{-1}^1
\left(\int\limits_0^1 \left(u^2v^2-\sqrt{2}uv^3-\sqrt{2}u^3v-4u^2v^2+u^2v^2\right)du\right)dv=$$
$$=\int\limits_{-1}^1
\left(\int\limits_0^1 \left(-2u^2v^2-\sqrt{2}uv^3-\sqrt{2}u^3v\right)du\right)dv=$$
$$=-\int\limits_{-1}^1
\left(\int\limits_0^1 \left(2u^2v^2+\sqrt{2}uv^3+\sqrt{2}u^3v\right)du\right)dv=$$
$$=-\int\limits_{-1}^1
\left(
\Big[\frac{2}{3}u^3v^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}u^2v^3+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}u^4v \Big]_{u=0}^{u=1} 
\right)dv=$$
$$=-\int\limits_{-1}^1
\left(\frac{2}{3}v^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}v^3+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}v\right)dv=$$
$$=-\Big[
\frac{2}{9}v^3+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}v^4+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}v^2 
\Big]_{-1}^1
=$$
$$=-\frac{4}{9}$$

Comment: It looks completely correct...but the final result seems to be $\;\color{red}-\frac49\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, yeah, of course! Thanks!